# How to concatenate a new item with hooks in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the below structure:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to update the metrics with new data:

```
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>({});
  getServerResourceUsage(serverId, intervalTime)
    .then(res => {
      setData((state: any) => ({
        ...res.data.data,
        metrics: {
          time_series: state.metrics.time_series.concat(res.data.data.metrics.time_series)
        }
      }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error.response)
    })
    .finally(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    });
```

Now what I get is the below error:

[image]

I'm struggling to find out why state is empty and how can I even console log its value to debug the issue.

Comment: could you share your state too ?

Comment: @Fatur it's the callback for useState, I added the line.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you declare state, so it's not gives you an error in the first fetch.

```
const [data, setData] = useState<any>({
    metrics: {
        time_series: []
    }
});
```

And setState parameter is should be a new data instead a callback.

```
setData({
  ...res.data.data,
  metrics: {
    time_series: data.metrics.time_series.concat(res.data.data.metrics.time_series)
  }
});
```

Or you can spread existing time_series too:

```
setData({
  ...res.data.data,
  metrics: {
    time_series: [...data.metrics.time_series, ...res.data.data.metrics.time_series]
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was wrongly using concatenate on an object rather array, time_series is not an array (it is shown in the given picture), and that why would I remove that call back? based on the React JS Documentation for updating the previous state we better use call backs.

Comment: @MohammadA.Souri No, we shouldn't. This is the doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: take a look at this one: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates